# Import scenarios not working properly for me

Tags: acumatica

I have been working on import scenarios for mass updating BOM attributes, I believe this is a custom field added for our quality checks.

I have been able to do this once for one BOM but, i have tried again with the same scenario and not been able to figure it out.

Below is a screenshot of what i have been working with and the error i receive. Any help will be great!

Thanks in advance.

[Import Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTK1S.png)

I had also received the bellow errors:
Error: 1386 items have not been processed successfully. View name: Documents.
at PX.Api.SyMappingUtils.ImportData(SYProcess graph, SYMappingActive mapping, SYImportOperation operation, SYMappingActive updated)
at PX.Api.SyMappingUtils.ProcessMapping(SYProcess graph, SYMappingActive mapping, SYImportOperation operation)
at PX.Api.SYImportProcessSingle.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.b__0()
at PX.Concurrency.CancellationIgnorantExtensions.RunWithCancellationViaThreadAbort(Action method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at PX.Concurrency.CancellationIgnorantExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at PX.Concurrency.Internal.PXLongOperationPars.PopAndRunDelegate(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at PX.Concurrency.Internal.RuntimeLongOperationManager.PerformOperation(PXLongOperationPars p)
Error: 'Operation ID' cannot be found in the system.
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.FillWithValues(TNode item, TNode copy, IDictionary values, PXCacheOperation operation, Boolean externalCall)
The item OperationID is not found (restricted:False,external:True,value:70)
The item OperationID is not found (restricted:False,external:True,value:70)

Comment: I have solved it, I was missing the <Action: Save> at the end of the scenario!